# Meteor: Create filters for a collection server side and store them in a local collection. Good idea?

Tags: javascript, meteor

We have pretty big sets of documents that we want our users to be able to view and filter. To speed things up we're only sending a limited amount of documents down to the client. However, since we do need the clients to be able to filter the documents we need a way to send down the keys and values they can filter on. Based on the clients selection of filters we create a query for the documents. Say for instance that we have two documents like this:

{tags: ['foo'], user: 'Ken'}
{tags: ['bar', 'baz'], user: 'Barbie'}

In this case, the client should see that tags can be filtered on foo, bar and baz while user can be filtered on Ken and Barbie. Since the filters are just an aggregation of the data in the documents I dont want to create a collection for the filters and store it in the db. Instead I've been playing around with using

var Filters = new Meteor.Collection(null)

inside a publication. I query all documents I want to create filters for and then I insert the filters to the Filters collection. Using .observe on the Filters collection i send down the filters to the client as they get added.

The result of this is that each client creates a Filters collection on the server. Say that each of those collections contain about 50-400 filters like {tag: 'foo', count: 3}. To me that sounds as if it should be fine without draining the ram of the server, but I'm no computer scientist. Any input on this would be appreciated.

If you have any other ideas of how to create filters on the server would also be interesting to look at.

Thanks!

Comment: When i was confronted to tag problem, I implemented chosen.js & set a centralized collection for tags, users have the possibility to choose from this collection and they can add new one if they don't exists already in the tag collection. Once i need to filter out the related collection i run a simple query, just make sure to use an index. For my case the overhead of the tag collection is negligible, and what I loose in duplicated data I gain in speed this way its not a Meteor problem but a Mongodb one

Comment: This question has been sponsored by [CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/?ticket_id=122)! Get expert support for your personal code problems with bounties.

Answer (score 2):

How about you publish the entire collection with just the filter fields, using [field specifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#fieldspecifiers)? That way it's just like an extra collection with just the filters, and in the results you can choose to only display documents that don't just have a `tag` field.

However a better idea, in my opinion, is to do something similar to mohamed's suggestion, and normalize things a bit. Have a separate Tags collection that contains a tag name and id, and have a TagsUsers connection that stores the tag id and user id. That will make filtering much easier, because then you can simply publish the tags collection to the client, add/delete/edit tags only once, and easily filter the publish method on the server.

```
// Server publish method
// Return just users that the client has filtered
Meteor.publish('users', function (tagIds) { // tags is an array of tag ids ['foo', 'baz']
    var userIds = TagsUsers.find({ tagId: { $in: tagIds } }).map(function (connector) {
        return connector.userId;
    });

    return Users.find({ _id: {$in: userIds } });
});

// Client subscribe method
Meteor.subscribe('users', Session.get('tag-filters'));
```

**Note:** This was originally answered on [CodersClan](http://www.codersclan.net/ticket/122)

Comment: This is pretty much the same solution as using a new Meteor Collection(null) but instead of initializing and populationg the filters collection when the client subscribes you actually save all the data to the db and update it as new tags/users are added. It's merely a choice between allowing duplication and not, but I guess duplication makes a lot of sense in this case. Thanks for the advice! (Sidenote: The code in your answer wont be reactive. One would need to use .observe on the TagsUsers cursor and manually publish to the Users collection.)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question? Normalizing things like this should eliminate all duplication, was my point.